# Overlaying an image on another

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

I am using this code to show image

```
<img class="imgpath" />

<style>
    .imgpath{    
        width: 32px;
        height: 32px;
        background-image: url(/images/logout.png);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
</style>
```

but I am getting this
[image]

**What is causing this and how can I fix it?**
This is my image
[image]

Comment: With `<img />`, you are supposed to use html parameter `src` not css rule `background-image`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the `img` html tag, you are supposed to specify the `src`. Since you didn't, it displays a default small image showing that the browser couldn't get an image from `src`.

You have at least two possibilities depending on what you intend to do:

Use `src` and remove background css rules: `<img class="imgpath" src="/images/logout.png"/>`

Use another html tag, example: `<div class="imgpath"></div>`